# Почему питон не определяет модуль requests и html2text?

Tags: python-3.x

Версия питон - 3.6.4

Написал в программе:

```
import requests
```

перед этим установив с помощью `pip install` соответствующие модули,
запустив программу, выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/проекты/задачи.py", line 142, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Тоже самое с `html2text`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: Покажите, что выводит команда `pip list`

Comment: "что делать?" — показать вывод команд: `py -mpip show requests` и `py -mrequests.certs`

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в каком виртуальном окружении вы находитесь(и находитесь ли вообще). В любом случае - эти модули не входят в базовую поставку Python - и для начала их бы желательно установить - `pip install requests`. Судя по всему вы работает в ОС семейства Windows - вам сюда для ознакомления с установкой [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#id11) для начала.

Comment: Я в вопросе имел ввиду, что установил модули с помощью pip instal (ошибся, написав pip installer), pip я уже давно установил, изменив переменную path, далее я прописывал в командной строке pip install requests и pip install html2text, установка прошла успешно, но питон не увидел эти модули, и да, у меня Windows (7)